# Batch file to read all file contents into a single file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file to read all the text files in a folder and output the contents into one single file.

I have been successful in reading the file names into a single file but having trouble reading the contents of each into single file.

This is the code I have to output all filenames into single file

```
@echo off

set path= "C:\FolderFullOfTextFiles"
cd %path%

for %%a in (*) do @echo %%a>> C:\SingleFile.txt
```

Comment: [type](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html) them.

Comment: The recommended way to set a variable is `Set "VariableName=VariableValue"`, it is also not recommended to `Set` a variable named the same as a built-in important system variable, `%path%`. You could try `@Type "C:\FolderFullOfTextFiles\*.txt">"C:\SingleFile.txt"` or maybe even `@Copy /Y /A "C:\FolderFullOfTextFiles\*.txt" "C:\SingleFile.txt"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to set a variable is:

```bat
Set "VariableName=VariableValue"
```

It is also not recommended to `Set` a variable named the same as a built-in, important, system variable, `%path%`.

To output the content of the text file you can use the `Type` command.

Your code should therefore look more like this:

```bat
@echo off

set "pth=C:\FolderFullOfTextFiles"
cd /d "%pth%"

for %%a in (*.txt) do type "%%a">>"C:\SingleFile.txt"
```

However, the `Type` command should be able to perform the task directly without a `For` loop, by using a wildcard, `*`:

```bat
@Type "C:\FolderFullOfTextFiles\*.txt">"C:\SingleFile.txt"
```

And similarly, so could the `Copy` command:

```bat
@Copy /Y /A "C:\FolderFullOfTextFiles\*.txt" "C:\SingleFile.txt"
```

Comment: Note: both `copy` and `type`for could give unexpected results; when some of the files don't have a `CRLF` at the end, the first line of the next file will be appended to the last line of the current file. The `for` approach does always append a `CRLF` (resulting in additional empty lines), which may also be unwanted.